# Is there a specific reason for the lack of 'notation' and 'terminology' tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I feel like 'what does this notation mean' and 'what term would be used to describe this' questions come up/will come up a lot.

Comment: Probably fine, no reason other than not being created yet.

Comment: @SeanOwen does anyone think they're worth creating?  i presume i don't have the reputation to create them at this point

Comment: I suppose you can note questions you think need that tag and if it looks good I can create them

Comment: @SeanOwen okay.  i'm sure there are others, but i went looking for a `notation` tag for [this question](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/how-does-the-algorithm-with-the-complexity-of-on3-work), and a `terminology` tag for [this one](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5438/what-is-the-term-for-when-a-model-acts-on-the-thing-being-modeled-and-thus-chang).  i can look for others later.

Answer (score 2):

Reproducing a similar [question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/creating-a-new-tag-for-julia-language) from the Cross Validated's meta forum.

Creating tags just because there might be questions on the tag is unnecessary.

However, if there are any questions which might use the tag, then creating one is very much advised.

Comment: yea.  if you glance at the comments you'll see that it came up because of specific questions that i thought would benefit from those tags.  sean owen was kind enough to take care of this.